# What Is The Smallest Real Number?

Tags: trigonometry

Find the smallest real number $Z$ such that for all triangle angles $A$,$B$ , and $C$, the inequality $\sin^2 (A) + \sin^2 (B) - \cos(C) \leq Z$ holds.

Comment: The inequality you wrote doesn't mention Z at all.

Comment: Check your question. Maybe instead of $A$ at the end you would have meant $Z$. Or tell the source.

Comment: Very related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687974/sin2-alpha-sin2-beta-cos-gamma-m-given-that-the-sum-of-the-angle

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that the inequality is:
$$
\sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)-\cos(\pi-A-B)\leq Z,
$$
Here you have a 2-variable function, namely:
$$
f(x,y)=\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)-\cos(\pi-x-y),
$$
Then you have to solve:
$$
\nabla f=0,
$$
which translates to:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}_2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\sin(\pi-x-y)\cdot(-1)&=&0\\
2\sin(y)\cos(y)+\sin(\pi-x-y)\cdot(-1)&=&0\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Therefore:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}_\sin(2x)-\sin(\pi-x-y)&=&0\\
\sin(2y)-\sin(\pi-x-y)&=&0\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thus:
$$
\sin(2x)=\sin(2y),
$$
so:
$$
2x=2y+k\pi,\ k\in\mathbb{Z},
$$
i.e.:
$$
x=y+k\frac{\pi}{2},\ k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sin(2y)=\sin(\pi-y-k\pi/2-y),
$$
Finally:
$$
\sin(2y)=\sin(\pi(1-k/2)-2y),
$$
Find the correct $y^*$, find the minimum of $f(x(y^*),y^*)$ and find $z^*=f(x(y^*),y^*)$.

Comment: That is exactly what we have to solve! Could you elaborate on how to solve your last equation?

Comment: Edited, hope it helps.